# Is there any way to get node output socket current value with python?

Tags: python, node-editor, shaders, mathematics

I know that is possible to get the default value of any node, but is there any way to get the current output value of one node? Like in this example below:

[image]

[image]

I would like to get the output[0] current value, that would be 3 (2 + 1), through blender python API, is it possible?

Comment: I think since it's all evaluated at runtime it's not straightforward (or even possible ?) to plug into a shader tree and get evaluated values out of nodes using the python API. Obviously with this specific example it would be pretty easy, but I assume you would like to know the output of more complicated node trees

Comment: also the problem is, that often the result of a node isn't just one value, but an array or 2 or 3 dimensional array. e.g. gradient